# Distribution of Tickets

Tags: c++, algorithm

There are n people. Each person has an interest in a certain number of events. (Max 10). Now each person has a ticket of an event which may or may not be of his interest.

How many maximum people can have a ticket to an event they have an interest in by exchanging the tickets between them.

For example

Person A Interested In - Event1, Event3
              Has Ticket - Event 4

Person B Interested In - Event 2, Event 4
              Has Ticket - Event 1

Person C Interested In - Event 8
              Has Ticket - Event 4

Person A and B can exchange tickets and go their events. C cannot. So answer is 2

**I would like to know how to approach this solution**

Comment: The first thing to notice is that it doesn't matter *who* originally holds a ticket.  All that matters is how many different people the *pool* of tickets can satisfy.

Comment: @j_random_hacker that's assuming that people are ready to give up tickets they want in order to maximize some irrelevant (to them) global function.

Comment: Seems like a Forrest problem with A having edges to Events 1 and Events 3 similar for B ans so on. You could then brute force doing a search on the forrest and removing the elements if an exchange succeeds. Is there a particular time complexity you are aiming for?

Comment: @n.m.: I see what you mean -- "my" optimal solution could result in a person who already had a ticket that they wanted having to swap that ticket for one they didn't want.  IMHO this is *not* ruled out by the question as written, but the OP should clarify whether this is acceptable.

Comment: Yes ! Our purpose is to maximize the number of people going to the event. So it is completely acceptable @j_random_hacker

Comment: In that case, this is the bipartite maximum matching problem: create a vertex in A for each person, and a vertex in B for each ticket, and an edge (u, v) whenever person u likes ticket v.  You can solve it optimally in O(n^3) time with the Hungarian Algorithm or maximum flow techniques.

Comment: Recommend removing the c++ tag and possibly moving to a different SE site (programming). It's an interesting problem, though.

Comment: @j_random_hacker : Using the Hungarian algorithm is a bit extreme since there is a unit weight on each edge. Better algorithms are Ford-Fulkerson, or Hopcroft-Karp for example.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like what we do in a so called Math Trade. Basically it's a way of collecting data about each participant's "collection" of items they offer for trade, and checking this against each participant's "wants", then trying to maximize the amount of trades, so that as many participants as possible can receive something they want.

This approach maximizes trades, and therefore trades are made in circles. I.e. trades don't have to be direct, so that Person A might give something to Person B, but might receive something from Person C. (a high amount of trust is involved in trades such as these)

Would this kind of circular trading be appropriate for your solution, or are you just looking for direct trades? (A gives to B, B gives to A)

If you want a concrete example, the software I usually use for this is called TradeMaximizer, and it is open source, so you can easily find it on SourceForge and dig through it, should you want to.

Sorry if this wasn't immensely helpful, first time posting, and couldn't add a comment!

Comment: Didn't know that this problem was of such "direct" interest!  Enjoyed reading Chris Okasaki's description of the algorithm used in TradeMaximizer :)